# Get info of an object in a ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I've created an `ArrayList` where I put some objects. When I create an object, I can retrieve some info by doing :

```
objectX.getActivityName();
```

My problem is when I put all my objects in my ArrayList, I can't access to my getActivityName Example :

```
for (Object temp:tabRegristre) {
        System.out.println("TEMPS : " + temp); // I want to show the temp object Activity Name not all the info of the object.

    }
```

Is there any solution to show only some info of my object from the for each loop? Instead of printing the object itself?

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, you could use generics and maybe an interface if you want to put object of different types into a list.

Comment: Since you're the one implementing the `toString()` method of the object, you are in full control of how much information that returns.

Comment: Why is `temp` type `Object`? I hope it's not because the list has mixed objects, because that is a bad design. So why aren't `temp` the type of object that `tabRegristre` contains?

Comment: Nop! All the object are the same type. the temp are only to print each object from the arraylist. I can print every object with the loop. No problem here. But I want to print ONE info from each object from the arraylist. This is my problem :(

Comment: Use `for (MySpecificClass temp:tabRegristre) {...` instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

## Generics

You need to learn about [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) and using angle brackets `<` & `>`. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

For a brief class definition, use the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature in Java 16. (Or use a conventional class.)

```
public record Activity ( String name , LocalDate when ) {}
```

Make a couple of those objects.

```
Activity brunch = new Activity( "Brunch" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.MARCH , 15 ) ) ;
Activity meeting = new Activity( "Meeting" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.APRIL , 23 ) ) ;
```

Define your collection. Notice how we use the angle brackets to tell the compiler that we want to restrict this list to containing only objects of type `Activity`.

```
List< Activity > activities = new ArrayList< Activity >() ;
```

The compiler can infer the class `Activity` on the right side of assignment `=`. So no need to repeat.

```
List< Activity > activities = new ArrayList<>() ;
```

Add your objects to the collection.

```
activities.add( brunch ) ;
activities.add( meeting ) ;
```

Retrieve each object. Print date. The accessor method carries the same name as its property. So `when()` is the accessor method for our `LocalDate` property named `when`.

The compiler knows that only `Activity` objects went into the collection, so retrieved items must be `Activity` objects. No need for casting ([explicit type conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Explicit_type_conversion)).

```
for( Activity activity : activities ) 
{
    System.out.println( activity.when() ) ;
}
```